# Correlated constrasting dependent variables (X positive Y1, X negative Y2, but Y1 positive Y2)?

Tags: correlation

everyone, not sure if I do this appropriately. I wish to raise a related question: If I got

X positively related to Y1, and 
X1 negatively related to Y2 (both in GLM), however 
the correlation coefficient between Y1 and Y2 is positive and significant (using SPSS).

How can I interpret such result? Shouldn't Y1 and Y2 also negatively correlated? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think they have to be negatively correlated? They don't necessarily have to be, as long as the [covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) of the triplet is [positive definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-semidefinite_matrix#Negative-definite.2C_semidefinite_and_indefinite_matrices). For example, if ${\rm cor}(X,Y_1) = .5, {\rm cor}(X,Y_2) = -.5$ and then ${\rm cor}(Y_1, Y_2)$ could be anywhere in the open interval $(-1,.5)$ to still produce a valid covariance matrix. Some information about the magnitude of these correlations would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean "correlated" when you say "related". 
It is certainly possible depending on the level of correlation between your variables.

As an example

```
x = rnorm(100)
eps = rnorm(100)
y = x + 2 * eps
z = x - 2 * eps

cor(x, y) # 0.4684695
cor(x, z) # 0.4726246
cor(y, z) # -0.5571685
```